# unupvote without any change in question?

Tags: support

This is  [my question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/34452/how-can-we-identify-layer-two-device-in-a-network-or-what-are-those-device-effec), yesterday I realized it is unupvote and I understand you can not downvote or unupvote a Q or A unless it has been edited.
look at my question and see last time was edited and look at the following picture.
[my repuatation](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/30070/r1w?tab=reputation)
my question is how is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> yesterday I realized it is unupvote and I understand you can not downvote or unupvote a Q or A unless it has been edited

You are correct, after a user casts a vote it becomes locked after a short time. This means a user cannot change their vote which helps prevent things like "rage vote reversals" or other abuses that would otherwise take place.

However, if this lock was permanent there would be no recourse if the original post a user voted on was changed. For example, imagine you down vote a bad post and your vote gets locked. The OP edits their post to significantly improve it and address the issues that caused you to down vote in the first place. Your vote may no longer reflect how you currently view the question.

Or the opposite can take place. An OP edits their post and you now believe it no longer deserve the up vote that you previously gave it. In either case, the edit triggers all previous votes to be unlocked so now you can change your vote to accurately reflect how you feel about the new version of the post.

> look at my question and see last time was edited and look at the following picture.
>   my repuatation
>   my question is how is this possible?

Once the votes are unlocked, there is no time limit to when a user can then change their vote. There are several reasons for this, primarily that users are not notified every time an edit is made to a post they voted on at some point (and most users would find this highly annoying especially if they vote frequently). Users may also only be infrequent visitors to the site or may be absent from a community for a prolonged period for any number of reasons.

So a user may not see the edit to a post within any certain period of time (if ever). But if they do see it, and it changes their opinion on how they voted on the post, they should have the ability to make that change.

Answer (score 1):

If you have never voted on a question or answer, and you have sufficient reputation to do so, you can certainly vote either direction at any time. If you have already voted on the question or answer, what you cannot do is change your vote unless the question has been edited.

Comment: The question was edited.

Comment: OK, once it was edited, then whoever voted up on it is free to change the vote at any time after the edit. Votes are anonymous, so there is no way to know who did that, but it is perfectly fine, and there is nothing wrong.